Detecting a specific type of invalid JSON file
I have JSON-like records being written by sensors.
The files are not valid because they look like concatenated records like the following:
  {
    "timestamp": "2024-07-17T12:31:12Z",
    "source_ip": "10.0.0.2",
    "source_port": 5678,
    "destination_ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "destination_port": 443,
    "protocol": "UDP",
    "bytes_sent": 800
  }
  {
    "timestamp": "2024-07-17T12:31:12Z"
  }
  {
    "timestamp": "2024-07-17T12:31:12Z"
  }

There are no leading and trailing square brackets and there are no commas between the records.
I can clean this up with jq easily enough if I can detect the issue. Not all files are broken like this, other files are properly formatted. Also, these files can be large (hundreds of Gb) so I am using ijson. They are customer files, I have no control over their formatting or content, I can only deal with it.
What's the ijson way to determine if a file is invalid per the above or not? This seems to work but it feels like I am killing an ant with a sledgehammer:
def test_file_for_array_markers(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        try:
            for record in ijson.items(file, 'item'):
                return isinstance(record, dict)
        except ijson.JSONError as e:
            return False

While the above may work, I don't think it is the best way.  Running with what Rodrigo said,  I am now trying to read the files using:
for record in ijson.items(file, 'item', multiple_values=True):

If I remove the multiple_values flag I get the "trailing garbage" error which is fine.  But when I add it, I get nothing at all. I never enter the for loop.  I amended the question above to include an actual example of what I am reading.

That's a perfectly valid file; it just happens to be valid JSONL (JSON Lines) rather than valid JSON.  ijson has a multiple_values = True option that can handle this (you may need to update it, as this appears to be a fairly recent addition).

I think JSON lines would still need quoted property names, that example fails https://jsonlines.org/validator/

This seems to work so you have a valid way? It is the way.

ijson maintainer here. As indicated by @jasonharper this is no valid JSON because of the multiple top-level elements, but ijson has the multiple_values flag for that. However, are records really like {a:1, ... or like {"a": 1, ...}? The former is also invalid JSON.

As I said above, the internals of the records are fine.  It's the "near json" aspect of the lack of separators and square-brackets. where "fine" means that ijson likes them very much :-D

Why is the question modified with now perfectly valid JSON?

It is invalid JSON. valid json requires a single top-level element, and these records should be comma-sep.  Too many readers couldn't get past the unimportant bits of the question to understand what I was asking.

for only parses first element and then returns. Check if all are dicts.
You script return None when there are no elements. No idea if this is correct or not.
def test_file_for_array_markers(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        try:
            return all(isinstance(record, dict) for record in ijson.items(file, 'item'))
        except ijson.JSONError as e:
            pass
    return False


Right, in all the examples I have, either I have an array of records separated by commas, or I have a list of records separated by newlines.  So checking the file for a leading "[" would actually be enough for my specific problem.  My files are hundreds of Gbs,  so I don't want to read them all to make the determination on how to parse them.

and "None" is falsey in Python, so I'd probably skate through I didn't think of the case.

The "ijson way" to determine if a file is invalid per the above (i.e., whether it contains one or more top-level elements) would be to try to process it fully and check whether errors arise (you can use the basic_parse function since it's the fastest and you're not interested in the actual results, only whether it parses or not). If you get no errors, the file is valid as-is.
If you get errors, try again with multiple_values=True. If you get no errors, then it was invalid due to there being multiple top-level values. If you get errors, then it's invalid because of something else (e.g., wrong syntax somewhere else within each document).
Going through the file twice though is obviously not great. Assuming you not only want to check the validity of the files, but also actually process their data, you'd want to restructure your program in a way that a single pass suffices.

...hundreds of gigabytes per file.  many such files. and time is short.

I added a piece of the problematic file to the question.  The file is full of those.

I also added a multiple_values flag per the edited question but it seems to cause the file to be ignored.

What do you mean by "ignored'? Reading between the lines, if you're expecting ijson.items to yield each of these top-level elements then you need to use an empty prefix.
